# PHP Get text before and after a certain word or phrase

Tags: php, email

I have emails coming into a mailbox and i am using the PHP function `imap_open` to get the emails.

every email looks like:

*You have a new message from 447********** saying Thank you. :)
You may reply to this email and it will be converted into an SMS text message!
If you need replies back to your email to SMS messages then either purchase a dedicated reply number, or set your default sendername to Simple Replies (Settings->E2S)
Type ## at the end of the reply to prevent unwanted text being converted (e.g. signature, advert, disclaimers, previous reply text).
Many thanks, the Textlocal.com team.*

so i want to get the actual message. in the above example the message is:

```
Thank you :)
```

how can i get just this part of the email?

Comment: is only Thank you :) is always outputted ??

Answer (score 1):

**Assuming the prefix/suffix to each message is a constant number of characters...** (as you stated in your question)

This is a q&d answer so I won't count the exact number of chars int he two strings. Let's say there are 10 chars in the first string to strip, and 150 in the second. The chars in between are your message:

```
$msg = 'You have a new message from 447*** saying Thank you. :) You may reply to this email and it will be converted into an SMS text message! If you need replies back to your email to SMS messages then either purchase a dedicated reply number, or set your default sendername to Simple Replies (Settings->E2S) Type ## at the end of the reply to prevent unwanted text being converted (e.g. signature, advert, disclaimers, previous reply text). Many thanks, the Textlocal.com team.*';

$msg = substr(substr($msg, 0, -150),10);

echo $msg;
```

If the number of chars is not constant, then you must first use `strpos()` to find the position where the desired part of the message begins/ends, and then use those figures in the code above.

---

Okay, I had to test this, so I ended up counting them. The operative line is:

```
$msg = substr(substr($msg, 0, -417), 42);
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using regular expressions :

```
$message = "You have a new message..."; // this is the message you receive.

$par1 = explode("saying ", $message); // temp variable

$par2 = explode(" You may reply", $par1[1]); // another temp variable

$text = $par2[0]; // this is the text you wanted to get.
```

`par1` and `par2` aren't necessary, a single one-liner like

```
$text = explode(" You may reply", explode("saying ", $message)[1])[0];
```

works fine on my side but it looks like your text editor somehow finds a syntax error in there, so I updated my code.

Comment: i am getting an error on the second line of your code

Comment: in dreamweaver i get a syntax error on line 2

Comment: :) fair enough. take a look here: http://postimg.org/image/lpbt6cma5/

Comment: I just tried your edit and echoed $text but its displaying nothing. If i display $message (the first variable) it displays the whole email body but $text there is nothing

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to escape the message with double quotes(") or any other symbols. That makes parsing a bit easier. Example:

```
$string = 'You have a new message from 447*** saying "Thank you. :)" You may reply...';

$string = explode('"', $string);

echo $string[1];
```

It returns Thank you :).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression for this:

```
$pattern = '~message from \d{6} saying (.*) You may~';
if(preg_match($pattern, $text, $matches)) {
    $message = $matches[1];
}

echo $message;
```

In the above regex, `\d{6}` is supposed to match the phone number. `6` needs to be changed accordingly.

Outputs:

```
Thank you. :)
```

[**Online demo.**](https://eval.in/73191)